# uneven data size on cassandra nodes

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am struggling to understand why my Cassandra nodes have uneven data size.

I have a cluster of three nodes. According to `nodetool ring`, each node owns 33.33%. Still disk space usages are uneven.

```
Node1: 4.7 GB (DC: logg_2, RAC: RAC1)
Node2: 13.9 GB (DC: logg_2, RAC:RAC2)
Node3: 9.3 GB (DC: logg_2, RAC:RAC1)
```

There is only one keysapce.

```
keyspace_definition: |
 CREATE KEYSPACE stresscql_cass_logg WITH replication = { 'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'logg_2' : 2, 'logg_1' : 1};
```

And there is only one table named `blogposts`.

```
table_definition: |
  CREATE TABLE blogposts (
        domain text,
        published_date timeuuid,
        url text,
        author text,
        title text,
        body text,
        PRIMARY KEY(domain, published_date)
  ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (published_date DESC)
    AND compaction = { 'class':'LeveledCompactionStrategy' }
    AND comment='A table to hold blog posts'
```

Please help me to understand it why each node has uneven datasize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ownership is how much data is owned by the node.

> The percentage of the data owned by the node per datacenter times the
> replication factor. For example, a node can own 33% of the ring, but
> show 100% if the replication factor is 3.
>
> Attention: If your cluster uses keyspaces having different replication
> strategies or replication factors, specify a keyspace when you run
> nodetool status to get meaningful ownship information.

More information can be found here:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsStatus.html#toolsStatus__description

> NetworkTopologyStrategy places replicas in the same datacenter by walking the ring clockwise until reaching the first node in another rack.
>
> NetworkTopologyStrategy attempts to place replicas on distinct racks because nodes in the same rack (or similar physical grouping) often fail at the same time due to power, cooling, or network issues.

Because you only have two racks(RAC1 and RAC2), you are placing node 1 and node 3's replicas in node 2, which is why it is bigger.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/architecture/archDataDistributeReplication.html